# beyond compare script for folder synchronisation

Tags: beyondcompare

I am writing a Beyond Compare script which will sync two folders. Consider these folder structures:

```
Folder1
-------
SubfolderA
    --FileA(modified)
    --FileB(new)
SubfolderB
    --FileC
FileD(modified)


Folder2
-------
SubfolderA
    --FileA
FileD
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is that after syncing them, only the files and folders pertaining to Folder2 should be copied to it.

So in this case

```
-the modified ones and the new ones in the SubfolderA should be copied on its counterpart

-SubfolderB should not be copied or created as there is no such subfolder in Folder2. 

-Whereas the modified FileD should be copied.
```

What should go along with the `select` and `update` or `sync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after waiting for some time and not finding an answer I posted the same question to one the developers of the Beyond Compare team. He said its not possible in the current version. But there is a workaround for it.

What we can do is `hardcode` the values of the folders that we don't need in the filter list and this will take care of it.

So for our example we can make a script like

```
filter "-SubfolderB\"
load c:\Folder1 c:\Folder2
sync update:left->right
```